# Verify returned list with a list in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a function that returns me a single list.  I'm trying to take what is returned and find if it exists in the list I already have.  Am I missing another 'for' loop to iterate through cat_colors list?  Or is the 'color' returned in a way that I can't match it in the list?  Trying to understand it and if you have a better solution?

```
for cat in cat_names:
    color = Get_Color(cat)
    print cat_colors
    print color

    if color not in cat_colors:
        print "fail"
    else:
        print "pass"
```

output from print:

```
['brown', 'grey', 'white', 'black', 'red', 'orange', 'green', 'blue']
['brown']
fail

['brown', 'grey', 'white', 'black', 'red', 'orange', 'green', 'blue']
['grey']
fail

...
```

Answer (score 4):

`['brown']` *isn't* in `['brown', 'grey', 'white', 'black', 'red', 'orange', 'green', 'blue']`. The string `'brown'` is.

You have two options here. If you know that `color` will always be a one-element list, you can do:

```
if color[0] in cat_colors:
   ...
```

If not, you could do:

```
if any(c in cat_colors for c in color):
   ...
   # or all(c in cat_colors for c in color) based on your needs
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check for color not in cat_colors. Instead you are checking with cat not in cat_colors.

Change your code like this

```
for cat in cat_names:
    color = Get_Color(cat)
    print cat_colors
    print color

    if color[0] not in cat_colors:
        print "fail"
    else:
        print "pass"
```

Comment: Hmm, well that's true, but also won't get him the desired result. I didn't notice that.

Comment: @AdamSmith Failed to notice color was a list :p

Comment: We're even then, since I failed to notice he was testing `if cat in cat_colors` :)

Comment: Sorry it is like this...   if color not in cat_colors:

Comment: I see what you are saying, so I need to say the first item in the list, not the list.

Comment: @user3203920 Now it makes more sense ;)

Comment: Yes. You cant check a list with a list. Your end goal is check whether the color is in that list. And i dont know why your Get_Color method returns a list. You should probably return the value of the list like color[0] from that method. So it will be easier for you to check if color not in cat_colors instead of color[0].

Answer (score 0):

Your `Get_Color(cat)` function must return a **string**
but it returns a **list** 
that's why you are not getting correct output

```
eg.
l1=['a','b','c','d']
l2=['a',['b'],['c','d']]

['b'] in l1
False
'b' in l1
True
['b'] in l2
True

['c'] in l2
False
['c','d'] in l2
True
```

Comment: Please take a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: I guess my next question would be, could I convert that to a string to verify?

Comment: since your **color** has only one item
You can just use
 **color[0]**  not in cat_colors

Answer (score 0):

And if you have cats with more than one color and you wanna know which colors of this perticular cat are in cat_colors:

```
def Get_Color(cat):
    if cat == 'whatevername1':
        color = ['brown', 'grey']
    elif cat == 'whatevername2':
        color = ['white', 'black', 'pink']
    elif cat == 'whatevername3':
        color = ['purple']
    return color
cat_names = ['whatevername1', 'whatevername2', 'whatevername3']
cat_colors = ['brown', 'grey', 'white', 'black', 'red', 'orange', 'green', 'blue']
print 'Valid colors:',cat_colors
for index,cat in enumerate(cat_names):
    color = Get_Color(cat)
    print 'Cat %s has colors:' %index,color
    valid_colors = set(cat_colors).intersection(color)
    if valid_colors:
        print 'Valid colors for cat %s are:' %index, valid_colors
    else:
        print "There are no valid colors for %s. Are you sure this is a real cat?"%index
```